# iPhone : how to kill background running application from springboard?

Tags: ios, springboard

How to kill all applications which are running into background in springboard.

is there any way to this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your app can only interact with what is inside its sandbox, and cannot change the state of other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot kill any other apps than your own. But to kill your app when you enter background, type:

```
         exit(0);
```

Inside the UIApplicationDelegate method:

```
             applicationDidEnterBackground
```

You will find that in mainly your app delegate class